# Calculating residuals of species distribution model and test for spatial auto correlation

Tags: r, autocorrelation

I built a species distribution model using random-forest. My training data consists of 971 records of species presence (71)/absence (900) and three environmental variables at systematically sampled points (4*4m, random starting point).

Training data:

```
str(train)
'data.frame':   971 obs. of  4 variables:
$ presence: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ v1     : num  0.18 0.18 0.24 0.24 0.75 0.7 0.27 0 0.29 0.77 ...
$ v2   : num  10 110 19 99 97 71 64 45 54 74 ...
$ v3   : Factor w/ 3 levels "cat1","cat2",..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 1 2 ...
```

model:

```
model <- randomForest(as.factor(presence) ~ v1 + v2 + v3, data = train, classwt = c(0.5, 0.5))
```

Note that I do not have the location of these points, just a table with the field measurements.

My test data (test) consists of 1019 records of the same variables including their coordinates at location B. Additionally I have mapped the species occurrence at location B (adjacent to A). So I applied the model on that data:

```
prediction <- predict(model, newdata = test, type="prob")
```

I set `type="prob"`because I wanted to predict the occurrence probability of the species.

The data I generated and want to test against the observed occurrence looks like this:

```
str(prediction_data)
'data.frame':   1019 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ x        : num  180574 180575 180576 180576 180576 ...
 $ y        : num  226954 226953 226951 226953 226955 ...
 $ v1    : num  0.1131 0.5996 0.7187 0.5885 0.0611 ...
 $ v2   : num  10 110 19 99 97 71 64 45 54 74 ...
 $ v3   : Factor w/ 3 levels "cat1","cat2",..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 1 2 ...
 $ occurrence_prob   : num  0.3252 0.1826 0.0909 0.1014 0.4195 ...
 $ occurrence_obsv : int  0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 ...
```

Now I have problems figuring out how to test and account for spatial auto-correlation in my model considering my study design. I read a lot of literature about the topic and I think I understand that the problem lies in the spatial auto correlation of the residuals. But here already lies my first doubt:

What are the residuals of my model? How can I calculate them?

I did a classification although I used the parameter `type="prob"` in the prediction function to get the occurrence probability. One way I can think of to get a map (or any geographic representation) of the model residuals would be to transform the occurrence probability to a binary format (0/1) and subtract it from the observed occurrence. I could then go on and test the map of the difference of the observed and predicted occurrence (model residuals?) for spatial auto-correlation by calculating moran´s I.

Would this be an appropriate way to test for spatial auto-correlation (sac)?

In case the model residuals test positive for SAC my guess is I will not be able to do anything about it because my training data is not geographical referenced - right?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a coding question since you already have a possible solution that would be trivial to implement. It appears to be a "what method is valid" Q and should be moved to CV.com. I think it should be improved by adding better  model description of the data situation and modeling assumptions.

Comment: I guess you are right - thanks. I tried to improve my question too